# Is it possible to use UINavigationBar appearance to config differenct bar backgroundColor for differenct controller?

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I have a navigation stack like this : TabBarController -> NavigationController->ControllerA-> ControllerB.

The ControllerA and ControllerB are pushed into the NavigationController.
And I want the ControllerA's navigationBar's backgroundColor is **RED**, and the  ControllerB's navigationBar's backgroundColor is **GREEN**.

I am already tried the appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses. But because the bar is belonged to the NavigationController. it was above the ControllerA& ControllerB in the hierarchy . So this appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses seems can't work.

Is there anyway to make this work with UINavigationBar appearance?

Answer (score 0):

I would make each view controller responsible for setting the nav bar's color in its `viewWillAppear` method. This ensures the nav bar has the appropriate color based on which view controller is in view.

Instead of using the `appearance...` methods, setup the colors directly on the specific nav bar. Each view controller can access the nav bar via:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar
```

If you'd rather have some other class control the colors, you could have the class set itself as the navigation controller's `delegate` and implement the `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` delegate method. Set the nav bar color based on which controller will be shown.